# Authentication error in APi calls with Google PubSub

Tags: ajax, google-api, google-cloud-messaging, google-authentication

I want to push/pull messages to topic on Google Cloud PubSub service. I need to fetch these messages with AJAX without promoting login/permissions screen to end user (i.e. end user can use this service without login). I have tried to add key={spiKey} in query string, but unable to get data every time get 401 error

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected  OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
 "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

Comment: please supply a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve we cant help you debug your code without being able to see the problem.    You cant mix Oauth2, service accounts and api keys.  These are three different things.

Comment: Hey, Can i use any key to authenticate user for Google Cloud API calls. As per requirements of my project I can't show permission window/popup to end user.